# What's wrong this use of sort function in C++11?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11

I made this program for taking in input in two vectors ( long long int considering the fact that the numbers can be really large that a normal int cannot accomodate ) and then I wish to sort them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool myfunct1( A first, A second );
bool myfunct2( A first, A second );

class A
{
    public:
        long long int foo;
};

int main (void)
{
    vector<A> values1(1000);
    vector<A> values2(1000);
    int temp1 = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
    int faltu;
    while (temp1<n)
    {
        cin>>faltu;
        values1[temp1].foo = faltu;
        temp1++;
    }
    while (temp2<n)
    {
        cin>>faltu;
        values2[temp2].foo = faltu;
        temp2++;
    }

    sort(values1.begin(), values1.end(),&myfunct1);  // Sorting the elements in ascending order
    sort(values2.begin(), values2.end(),&myfunct2);  // Sorting in descending order

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        printf("%lld",values1[i].foo);    
    printf("\n");

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        printf("%lld",values2[i].foo);    
    printf("\n");
}


bool myfunct1( A first, A second ) 
{   
    if ( first.foo < second.foo )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool myfunct2( A first, A second ) 
{   
    if ( first.foo > second.foo )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

When I see the output of the vectors after sorting, it is not correct. For eg for the input as : 
`2 1 3` `7 8 9` ( for the two vectors ), it shows the output as, `000` `987`. Why is this happening?
I think that the sort function is not functioning properly. But I did sorting after

Comment: Also, why use the `if` statement in the functions? You can just as well write `return first.foo < second.foo;`

Comment: @Joachim, I already did that but I forgot to include it in the code that I posted here. There is some other error. I did what you just wrote, but still it is not showing the correct output.

Comment: `vector<A> values1(1000)` - what does this do?

Comment: What is `n`? How is it declared`How is it *initialized*?

Comment: What is the point of the class?

Comment: "...for the input as : `2 1 3` `7 8 9`". Really? You created two vectors of `1000` elements each, all elements initialized to `0`. Then you set some of these elements (3 in each vector apparently) to some non-zero values, leaving remaining 997 elements as zeros. And then you sorted the vectors. Why do you find it surprising that those 997 zeros drifted to the beginning of the vector after sorting in ascending order?

Comment: This is almost a http://sscce.org but is not compilable, since `n` is not declared.

Comment: `vector<A> values1(1000);` is definitely causing the problem (creating vectors of 1000 zeroes). Should be `vector<A> values1(n)` or `values1()` + using `vector::push_back`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the first vector is printing 000 is probably because you initialize the vector with 1000 initial values, which probably default to 0. I am not 100% sure of this, but the reason the second sort works is because the largest numbers are placed first. In the case of the first, there are 997 0s before your 1,2,3. What I would suggest is (if your n is 3), initialize the vectors with just 3 and do your test.

Also, IDK why you are initializing your vector to have 1000 elements of type A immediately, but you can also attempt to test your program and the sort function by not initializing the vector with any elements and utilizing the push_back method on it instead to insert your variables.

Your syntax is otherwise perfectly alright, there should be no issue with the sort.

Comment: The elements of the vector are initialized with `A()`; in this case, it zero initializes.